# C#: How to add xml element at specific position in multiple records of xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have large xml file which has multiple tables. I want to add one element at a specific position. I tried, but in my case, the element is getting added at last, which is not desirable for my scenario.

My tables are in xml. `TickerBroker , Broker, BrokerTab and TickerBrokerDateFormatMap`

I have multiple Broker element, and when I am adding a new Broker, then it is getting added in xml file after **TickerBrokerDateFormatMap** element at the end. I want to add Broker element at the end of last Broker element in xml file.

If no Broker element exist in xml file, then my Broker element should be adding at the end of last **TickerBroker** element.

Here I am giving my sample xml data, which is a bit long.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<TickerBrokerDateMap>
  <TickerBroker>
    <Ticker_Id>ADBE</Ticker_Id>
    <Ticker_Id_auto>ADBE</Ticker_Id_auto>
  </TickerBroker>

  <Broker ID="MV-P1" Ticker_Id="ADBE" BrokerCategory="Cascade" Client="">
    <Broker_Id>25</Broker_Id>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>MV-P1</Broker>
      <TAB>QIS</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>25</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings>3Q 2019</ReviewedEarnings>
      <Pre-Post>Post</Pre-Post>
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>MV-P1</Broker>
      <TAB>BS</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>25</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings>3Q 2019</ReviewedEarnings>
      <Pre-Post>Post</Pre-Post>
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>MV-P1</Broker>
      <TAB>METRICS</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>25</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings>3Q 2019</ReviewedEarnings>
      <Pre-Post>Post</Pre-Post>
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>MV-P1</Broker>
      <TAB>ESTIMATE</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>25</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings />
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>MV-P1</Broker>
      <TAB>EPS</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>25</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings>3Q 2019</ReviewedEarnings>
      <Pre-Post>Post</Pre-Post>
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
  </Broker>
  <Broker ID="UN" Ticker_Id="ADBE" BrokerCategory="Contributing" Client="">
    <Broker_Id>27</Broker_Id>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>UN</Broker>
      <TAB>ModelCover</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>27</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings />
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>UN</Broker>
      <TAB>Assumptions</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>27</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings />
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>UN</Broker>
      <TAB>Revenue Build</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>27</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings>4Q2019</ReviewedEarnings>
      <Pre-Post>Pre</Pre-Post>
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>UN</Broker>
      <TAB>Segment Breakout</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>27</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings />
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>UN</Broker>
      <TAB>Geographic Breakout</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>27</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings>4Q2019</ReviewedEarnings>
      <Pre-Post>Pre</Pre-Post>
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>UN</Broker>
      <TAB>Calcs</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>27</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings />
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>UN</Broker>
      <TAB>Debt</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>27</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings />
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>UN</Broker>
      <TAB>GAAP Income Statement</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>27</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings>4Q2019</ReviewedEarnings>
      <Pre-Post>Pre</Pre-Post>
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>UN</Broker>
      <TAB>Non-GAAP Income Statement</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>27</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings>4Q2019</ReviewedEarnings>
      <Pre-Post>Pre</Pre-Post>
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>UN</Broker>
      <TAB>Balance Sheet</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>27</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings>4Q2019</ReviewedEarnings>
      <Pre-Post>Pre</Pre-Post>
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>UN</Broker>
      <TAB>Cash Flow</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>27</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings>4Q2019</ReviewedEarnings>
      <Pre-Post>Pre</Pre-Post>
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>UN</Broker>
      <TAB>Disclosures</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>27</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings />
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
  </Broker>
  <Broker ID="BW" Ticker_Id="ADBE" BrokerCategory="NonContributing" Client="">
    <Broker_Id>28</Broker_Id>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>BW</Broker>
      <TAB>Adobe Model_Stifel</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>28</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings>4Q 2019</ReviewedEarnings>
      <Pre-Post>Pre</Pre-Post>
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>BW</Broker>
      <TAB>Disclaimer (Read first)</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>28</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings />
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>BW</Broker>
      <TAB>Sources</TAB>
      <Commnet1 />
      <Commnet2 />
      <Broker_Id>28</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings />
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
  </Broker>
  <Broker ID="PJ-C1" Ticker_Id="ADBE" BrokerCategory="Contributing" Client="">
    <Broker_Id>29</Broker_Id>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>PJ-C1</Broker>
      <TAB>IS</TAB>
      <Commnet1>Use Custom</Commnet1>
      <Commnet2>Use Custom</Commnet2>
      <Broker_Id>29</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings>4Q 2019</ReviewedEarnings>
      <Pre-Post>Pre</Pre-Post>
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>PJ-C1</Broker>
      <TAB>BS</TAB>
      <Commnet1>Use Custom</Commnet1>
      <Commnet2>Use Custom</Commnet2>
      <Broker_Id>29</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings>4Q 2019</ReviewedEarnings>
      <Pre-Post>Pre</Pre-Post>
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>PJ-C1</Broker>
      <TAB>CF</TAB>
      <Commnet1>Use Custom</Commnet1>
      <Commnet2>Use Custom</Commnet2>
      <Broker_Id>29</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings>4Q 2019</ReviewedEarnings>
      <Pre-Post>Pre</Pre-Post>
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
    <ALLTabsUnderBroker>
      <Broker>PJ-C1</Broker>
      <TAB>Segment Breakout</TAB>
      <Commnet1>Use Custom</Commnet1>
      <Commnet2>Use Custom</Commnet2>
      <Broker_Id>29</Broker_Id>
      <ReviewedEarnings>4Q 2019</ReviewedEarnings>
      <Pre-Post>Pre</Pre-Post>
    </ALLTabsUnderBroker>
  </Broker>
  <BrokerTab name="IS" Broker_Id="0" Ticker_Id="ADBE" Revise_Date="11-19-2019">
    <BrokerTab_Id>0</BrokerTab_Id>
    <Tab_index>0</Tab_index>
    <save_flag>true</save_flag>
    <isUSed>true</isUSed>
  </BrokerTab>
  <BrokerTab name="Drivers" Broker_Id="0" Ticker_Id="ADBE" Revise_Date="11-19-2019">
    <BrokerTab_Id>1</BrokerTab_Id>
    <Tab_index>1</Tab_index>
    <save_flag>true</save_flag>
    <isUSed>true</isUSed>
  </BrokerTab>
  <BrokerTab name="BS" Broker_Id="0" Ticker_Id="ADBE" Revise_Date="11-19-2019">
    <BrokerTab_Id>2</BrokerTab_Id>
    <Tab_index>2</Tab_index>
    <save_flag>true</save_flag>
    <isUSed>true</isUSed>
  </BrokerTab>
  <BrokerTab name="CF" Broker_Id="0" Ticker_Id="ADBE" Revise_Date="11-19-2019">
    <BrokerTab_Id>3</BrokerTab_Id>
    <Tab_index>3</Tab_index>
    <save_flag>true</save_flag>
    <isUSed>true</isUSed>
  </BrokerTab>
  <TickerBrokerDateFormatMap BrokerTab_Id="154" Broker_Id="29" Ticker_Id="ADBE">
    <StandardDate>2021 FYE</StandardDate>
    <ColumnCoordinate>AQ</ColumnCoordinate>
    <TickerBrokerDateFormatMaps_Id>168</TickerBrokerDateFormatMaps_Id>
    <BrokerDate StandardDate="2021 FYE" Broker_Id="29" BrokerTab_Id="154">
      <year>2021 FYE</year>
      <Quater>2021 FYE</Quater>
    </BrokerDate>
  </TickerBrokerDateFormatMap>
</TickerBrokerDateMap>
```

Here I am giving my C# code to add xml broker element, which is adding at the end of file, which is not desirable.

```
    string srclocalfile = @"C:\FILE1.xml";
    string strZipBrokerID = "10";
    string strSourceBrokerID = "12";
    string broker = "UN";

    XDocument xmlDocZip = XDocument.Load(srclocalfile);

    var zipbrokerrow = xmlDocZip.Descendants().Elements("Broker").FirstOrDefault(b => b.Attribute("ID").Value.ToString().Trim().Equals(broker));

    if (zipbrokerrow != null)
    {

        XElement oSubElm = null;
        XElement brokerelement = new XElement("Broker",
            new XAttribute("ID", broker),
            new XAttribute("Ticker_Id", strTicker),
            new XAttribute("BrokerCategory", zipbrokerrow.Attribute("BrokerCategory").Value),
            new XAttribute("Client", zipbrokerrow.Attribute("Client").Value),
            new XElement("Broker_Id", strSourceBrokerID));

        foreach (XElement e in zipbrokerrow.Descendants("ALLTabsUnderBroker"))
        {
            string _broker = e.Element("Broker").Value;
            string _TAB = e.Element("TAB").Value;
            string _Commnet1 = e.Element("Commnet1").Value;
            string _Commnet2 = e.Element("Commnet2").Value;
            string _Broker_Id = e.Element("Broker_Id").Value;
            string _ReviewedEarnings = e.Element("ReviewedEarnings").Value;

            oSubElm = new XElement("ALLTabsUnderBroker",
                new XElement("Broker", _broker),
                new XElement("TAB", _TAB),
                new XElement("Commnet1", _Commnet1),
                new XElement("Commnet2", _Commnet2),
                new XElement("Broker_Id", _Broker_Id),
                new XElement("ReviewedEarnings", _ReviewedEarnings));

            brokerelement.Add(oSubElm);

        }

        xmlDocZip.Root.Descendants("Broker").FirstOrDefault().Parent.Add(brokerelement);
        xmlDocZip.Save(srclocalfile);
    }
```

See, I am using XDocument class, so please post any sample code using **XDocument**. thanks

Comment: You made it too complicated : XElement dataMap = xmlDocZip.Root; dataMap.Add(brokerelement);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [XNode.AddAfterSelf Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.addafterself?view=netframework-4.8)

This methods do exactly what you want:

> Adds the specified content immediately after this node.

Example:

```
xmlDocZip.Root.Descendants("Broker").LastOrDefault()?.AddAfterSelf(brokerelement);
```

It's important to validate if LastOrDefault will not return null before call AddAfterSelf, otherwise it will throw an NullReferenceException.

```
// If xml has any Broker tag
if(xmlDocZip.Root.Descendants("Broker").Any())
{
    xmlDocZip.Root.Descendants("Broker").LastOrDefault().AddAfterSelf(brokerelement);
}
else if (xmlDocZip.Root.Descendants("TickerBroker").Any())
{
    xmlDocZip.Root.Descendants("TickerBroker").LastOrDefault().AddAfterSelf(brokerelement);
}
```